# how to verify password which is store in database as a hash value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to store password in an encrypted form. I have used sha256.
My code is as below

```
public static string ComputeHash(string plainText)
    {
        int minSaltSize = 4;
        int maxSaltSize = 8;

        Random random = new Random();
        int saltSize = random.Next(minSaltSize, maxSaltSize);

        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[saltSize];
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        rng.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes);

        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes = new byte[plainTextBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < plainTextBytes.Length; i++)
            plainTextWithSaltBytes[i] = plainTextBytes[i];

        for (int i = 0; i < saltBytes.Length; i++)
            plainTextWithSaltBytes[plainTextBytes.Length + i] = saltBytes[i];


        HashAlgorithm hash = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] hashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(plainTextWithSaltBytes);
        byte[] hashWithSaltBytes = new byte[hashBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
            hashWithSaltBytes[i] = hashBytes[i];

        for (int i = 0; i < saltBytes.Length; i++)
            hashWithSaltBytes[hashBytes.Length + i] = saltBytes[i];

        string hashValue = Convert.ToBase64String(hashWithSaltBytes);
        return hashValue;
    }
```

Now when user login i want to verify this password
How can i do that??

Comment: This may help http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take the plain text password from the user, hash it with the same algorithm and compare the freshly generated hash with the hash stored within the database. If both hashes are the same, the user entered the correct password.

#### Update

You use everytime a freshly random salt, thous leading to the different hashes. Simply make a new column within your database containing the salt used and take this one.

It is not a *security problem* to save the salt together with the hash. The salt will only prohibit the simple usage of pre-calculated rainbow-tables for a single hash-algorithm if it would be used directly. It doesn't give any clue about the real password that was used and also not about how the salt is combined with the plain-text password (prepend, append, inter-weaved, ...), so it can safely be stored next to the generated hash.

Comment: from above code suppose i give password as 123456 then every time the hash value is different

Comment: Can some one give the example or links for this

Comment: Can it be possible to remove the salt from the string and than to compare it... if yes than how?

Comment: @vaishali: No, this is not possible. The hash is a one-way calculation that can't be (easily) reverted. And to make the reversion even more complicated the salt will be added to the plain text before the hash is computed.